# Proving $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is an abstract surface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Suppose we have the maps $$x_1 : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2:(u,v) \mapsto [(1,u,v)]$$ $$x_2 : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2:(u,v) \mapsto [(u,1,v)]$$ $$x_3 : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2:(u,v) \mapsto [(u,v,1)].$$

I now want to prove that $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is an abstract surface with the patches $x_1, x_2, x_3$. To do this we have to show (all other conditions are valid) that for all $i,j \in \{1,2,3\}$ where $x_i(\mathbb{R}^2) \cap x_j(\mathbb{R}^2) \neq \emptyset$, the map $$ x^{-1}_j \circ x_i : x_i^{-1 } (x_i(\mathbb{R}^2) \cap x_j(\mathbb{R}^2)) \rightarrow  x_j^{-1 } (x_i(\mathbb{R}^2) \cap x_j(\mathbb{R}^2))$$ is a diffeomorphism (i.e. an invertible function where the function and the inverse are differentiable). I have no clue how to even start this...

Comment: Start by calculating for instance $x_1^{-1}$. So, what is $x_1^{-1}([\xi,\eta,\zeta])$? Next, combine this calculation with the definition of $x_2$ to calculate $x_1^{-1}\circ x_2$. What is $(x_1^{-1}\circ x_2)(u,v)$ (for $(u,v)$ in the correct domain of course)? Work very explicitly and concretely in this calculation; the others are similar.

Comment: @peek-a-boo $x_1^{-1}$ is the map that maps a point $[(1,u,v,)]$ (note we can write any point of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ like this if the first component differs from $0$) to $(u,v)$ and all the points that are a multiple of it. Am I on the right track?

Comment: yes that's right, so how would you write it in general? What is $x_1^{-1}([\xi,\eta,\zeta])$ if $\xi\neq 0$? Therefore the composition is....?

Comment: $\lambda \cdot (\eta, \zeta)$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. I don't see what the composition is because of the intersection in the domain and image...

Comment: be more explicit. that's the only way you can calculate the composition. Only use $\xi,\eta,\zeta$ in the final answer.

Comment: how can I be more explicit than this? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137219/discussion-between-peek-a-boo-and-geigercounter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O = (0,0,0) \in \mathbb R^3$. The space $\mathbb RP^2$ is the quotient of $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \{O\}$ by identifying $(a,b,c)$ with $(\lambda a, \lambda b, \lambda c)$ for all $\lambda \ne 0$. Since for each $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb R^3 \setminus \{O\}$ at least one of $a, b,c$ must be non-zero, we see that $\mathbb RP^2$ is the union of the three subsets
$$\mathbb RP^2_1 = \{[(a,b,c)] \mid a \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}, b, c \in \mathbb R \}$$
$$\mathbb RP^2_2 = \{[(a,b,c)] \mid b \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}, a, c \in \mathbb R\}$$
$$\mathbb RP^2_3 = \{[(a,b,c)] \mid c \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}, a, b \in \mathbb R \}$$
These sets are open in $\mathbb RP^2$ because their preimages under the quotient map $p : \mathbb R^3 \setminus \{O\} \to \mathbb RP^2$ are open. For example, we have $p^{-1}(\mathbb RP^2)= (\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}) \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.

Note that each element of $\mathbb RP^2_1$ has a *unique representative* of the form  $(1,u,v)$, similarly $\mathbb RP^2_2$ and $\mathbb RP^2_3$. Thus we can write
$$\mathbb RP^2_1 = \{[(1,u,v)] \mid u,v \in \mathbb R \}$$
$$\mathbb RP^2_2 = \{[(u,1,v)] \mid u,v \in \mathbb R \}$$
$$\mathbb RP^2_3 = \{[(u,v,1)] \mid u,v \in \mathbb R \}$$
These are the images of the maps $x_i$. Let us now determine $\mathbb RP^2_1 \cap \mathbb RP^2_2$ (the other intersections can be treated similarly).

$\xi \in \mathbb RP^2_1 \cap \mathbb RP^2_2$ means that both $\xi =  [(1,u,v)]$ and $\xi = [(u',1,v')]$. This means that there exists $\lambda \ne 0$ such that $1 = \lambda u', u =  \lambda 1 = \lambda, v = \lambda v'$, in other words $u \ne 0$, $u' = 1/u$ and $v' = v/u$. We can express this by the equivalent conditions $u' \ne 0$, $u = 1/u'$ and $v = v'/u'$.

Thus
$$x_1^{-1}(\mathbb RP^2_1 \cap \mathbb RP^2_2) = x_2^{-1}(\mathbb RP^2_1 \cap \mathbb RP^2_2) =  (\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}) \times \mathbb R .$$
The map $x_2^{-1} \circ x_1 : (\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}) \times \mathbb R  \to (\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}) \times \mathbb R$ has the form

$$(x_2^{-1} \circ x_1)(u,v) = x_2^{-1}([1,u,v]) = x_2^{-1}([1/u,1,v/u]) = (1/u,v/u) .$$
This is clearly differentiable, as is its inverse.